# Draw a vertical line representing the current date in d3 gantt chart

Tags: javascript, php, svg, d3.js

hi this maybe very easy for you guys i just need to draw a vertical line that represents the current date in my d3 gantt chart. i already figure out the values for my y i just having trouble in the value in my X because im using a time.scale in my x-axis. ill paste the codes that draws my gantt chart and the part where i draw my vertical line is located at the very bottom

```
initTimeDomain(tasks);
initAxis();

var numFormat = d3.format(",.0f");
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%b-%d");
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%b-%d").parse;

var svg = d3.select("#gantt_chart")
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("class", "gantt-chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) / tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate)
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");


 //this is the x-axis
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
 .transition()
 .call(xAxis)
 .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor","end")
    //.attr("dx", 35)
    //.attr("dy", 5);
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", -10)
    .attr("transform", function(d){return "rotate(-90)"});


 //this is the y-axis
 svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").transition().call(yAxis);




//this is the actual gantt
svg.selectAll(".chart")
 .data(tasks, keyFunction).enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("rx", 0)
  .attr("ry", 0)
 .attr("class", function(d){ 
 if(d.status > 70)
 { 
    return "bar-failed";
 }
 else if (d.status >= 51 && d.status <= 70){
    return "bar-killed";
 }
 else{
    return "bar-running";
 }
 }) 
 .attr("y", 0)
 .attr("transform", rectTransform)
 .attr("height", function(d) { return y.rangeBand(); })
 .attr("width", function(d) { 
     return (x(d.endDate) - x(d.startDate)); 
     })
.on("mouseover", function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("HandlerID: " + d.taskName  + "<br>" +  "startDate: " + dateFormat(d.startDate) + "<br/>" + 
                "endDate: " + dateFormat(d.endDate) + "<br/>" + "% Insertions: " + d3.round(d.status,2) + "%" + "<br/>" +
                "Insertions: " + numFormat(d.insertions) )                       
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
})
.on("mouseout",function(d){
        div.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
});


var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
today = parseDate(today);
//document.write(today);

svg.append("line")
.attr("x1", today)
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", today)
.attr("y2", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
.style("stroke-width", 2)
.style("stroke", "red")
.style("fill", "none");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just get the date today. No need to get its date, month, and year because it will return a string.
All you have to do is put the date in your `x` variable to jive with its domain

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();    //<<===== no need
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!   //<<===== no need
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();  //<<===== no need


svg.append("line")
.attr("x1", x(today))  //<<== change your code here
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("x2", x(today))  //<<== and here
.attr("y2", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
.style("stroke-width", 2)
.style("stroke", "red")
.style("fill", "none");
```

Comment: hey that was fast! i knew it i just lacking something!

Comment: in your example, i am not clear what the x function is or does. i imagine it has to map a date to an x value..but how do you implement it?

Comment: Depending on your usecase instead of `y1` = 0 you might want to draw from `y(0)` and the max might be `y(d3.max(myData, function(d) { return d.dataFieldYValues; })))`