# D3.js vertical line representing current point in time on a time scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to have a vertical line on my svg that represents the current time on an X-axis. The problem is that the x1 and x2 coordinates are very wrong.

My x-axis is a d3.time.scale().

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(2000, 0, 1, 0), new Date(2000, 0, 2, 0)])
        .range([0, 1800]);
```

Here is my xAxis, which I don't think it actually matters that much in this instance.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(d3.time.minute, 60)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"))
        .orient("top");
```

I really know and understand what this scale does, meaning the fact that it maps from a domain to a range (as explained in the official d3 docs).

I am still in doubt because say when I want to draw a vertical line, I am creating a new date 
`var today = new Date()` but when I pass it to the scale it doesn't appear  on the screen. 
If I log the value of today mapped by x it's totally wrong :

```
console.log(today) results in Thu Sep 22 2016 10:26:09 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) - which is OK
console.log(x(today)) results in -51059.03733651621 - which is WRONG (i.e. it's not in range (0, width)
```

Here is my code for creating and appending the line.

```
svg.append("line")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("x1", x(today))
            .attr("y1", margin.top)
            .attr("x2", x(today))
            .attr("y2", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .style("fill", "none");`
```

I have read [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418777/draw-a-vertical-line-representing-the-current-date-in-d3-gantt-chart) and tbh everything related on stack and google, and still can t crack why `x(today)` does not map to a relevant range. 
I also considered the fact that my domain is *back in time -> 2000*, and today it's in 2016 and changed my domain accordingly, but still the mapping is wrong.

Any help is appreciated folks. Thank you !

EDIT: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wLequ7e4/) is a fiddle that is NOT working, and [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv1rvurh/) that explains that I want to achieve, but it's basically hard-coded!

Comment: Can u provide a running version?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What bits do you think are missing from my post so I can add them? The svg runs, and everything works smoothly. I only have this problem with the line.

Comment: Is that your real domain? Do you realise that it starts and ends in 2000?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, that is the domain that I am using in the svg because all I need it to is to create a scale and divide it in 1h intervals and display the ticks. I do realize that, as written in the post. I have changed the interval to today and tomorrow and still the same issue.

Comment: @flashjpr Consider coordinate position (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) and the scale what u r created. Its more enough to draw the line in svg

Comment: @AravindCheekkallur Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve. While the y1 and y2 values are correct, as explained in the post and as you can see from the logs, the mapping from the x Scale returns something wrong.

Comment: Yep, I just read the last paragraph. So, in that case, edit your question with a domain that contains "today", otherwise your problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I think its a domain value not in the range or the domain is not the scope

Comment: @Aravind Can you please rephrase that?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Input value and the scale are not matching, i mean the date

Comment: I will provide a fiddle to show the exact error guys. 5 mins. Thanks a lot for your help so far.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Please check the fiddles in the post.

Comment: If the domain is set containing "today", it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fm6zx62j/ Therefore, your problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **fixed** thanks to the help of @GerardoFurtado who pointed out that if the DOMAIN is valid to the date I am passing (i.e. today is included in the domain;) it will produce a **valid output** (which in in the range interval).

My *extremely* **stupid** mistake was that even though I though that might be an issue, I did not took into consideration that **JS Dates start from 0** (January - 0).

When @GerardoFurtado added a valid interval to my domain, the line is being drawn correctly.

If this is at any use to someone, I will also add the bit that ensures that any time the app is being run, it will have a valid interval between **S**tart**O**f**D**ay of *today* and **S**tart**O**f**D**ay of *tomorrow.*

```
var x = new Date();
var today = new Date(x.getFullYear(),getMonth(),x.getDate(),0,0,0); 
var tomorrow = new Date(today);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rv1rvurh/1/) is an updated fiddle. Thank you very much for your input @GerardoFurtado and @Aravind Cheekkallur.

If anyone might read this, **be SURE that your *INPUT* is INCLUDED in your domain** !