# Vertical line in D3 plot move on zoom/pan

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to draw a vertical line marker in my graph in D3. It is modeled off of this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

My issue is that after I draw my line, it doesn't move as I zoom/scroll the graph. An example is shown below:

[image]

Currently, I have it calculated as a `d3.area()`.

```
this.pastDateArea = d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return this.x(this.props.pastDate.toDate()) }.bind(this))
    .y0(0)
    .y1(function(d) { return this.height }.bind(this))
```

It is appended as

```
var pastDateData = [{x:this.props.pastDate.toDate(), y:150}]
this.focus.append("path")
    .datum(pastDateData)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", this.pastDateArea)
```

and zoomed/brushed using

```
//zoom
var t = d3.event.transform;
this.x.domain(t.rescaleX(this.x2).domain());

//brush
this.svg.select(".zoom").call(this.zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .scale(this.width / (s[1] - s[0]))
    .translate(-s[0], 0));
```

I know there are similar questions to this one (namely, [Draw a vertical line representing the current date in d3 gantt chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418777/draw-a-vertical-line-representing-the-current-date-in-d3-gantt-chart)) but none of them include the zooming/panning features I have in my graph.

Please let me know if you need more information and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not updating the vertical bar with each zoom event. Using the code of the example you show, several things are done when the chart is zoomed, including as you note:

```
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());     // update x scale
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area); // redraw chart area
```

While you do give the new area the class of `area`, d3.select will only pick the first matching element. So, on zoom, only one `.area` element is updated (the first encountered, generally the first appended). But, replacing this with `d3.selectAll(".area")` will not generate the intended results as the area function referenced (`.attr("d",area)` ) is only used for the first area (that of the graph, not of the vertical bar).

A solution is to select each area (the chart and the bar) independently and update the area with their respective area generators. To do so, append the vertical bar with a unique class name, or an id and use that to select it later. Then when updating the graph on zoom or brush you can use:

```
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));              // update x scale
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);       // redraw chart area
  focus.select(".bar").attr("d", pastDateArea);// redraw vertical bar
```

Remember that this needs to be done for both zoom and brush. Also, in the given example, a clip path is assigned in the css for `.area`, so you need to keep that in mind as well.

Here's a [modified example](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/6074b2899c3c3ab6099cb60ea7a9527a).